# Выбрать год. Android

Tags: java, android, xml

Мне нужно, чтобы пользователь указал свой год рождения. Календаря мне дня этого слишком много. Нужен какой-то numeric, где я мог бы задать диапазон и пользователь выбрал один. Как такой элемент будет называться? EditText не подходит.

Comment: Такой элемент будет называться [`NumberPicker`](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/numberpicker.php) или `Spinner`, в зависимости от предпочитаемой логики выбора - прокрутка или раскрывающийся список.

Comment: И DatePicker тоже посмотрите